# Spring Boot: Json Response is not Mapping to Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to map this Json response I consume through a secured RESTful API; however, the mapping is for some reason not happening correctly as I keep getting a NULL response instead of populated object.

This is my entity:

```
@JsonTypeName("order")
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT ,use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class Order {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private long customerd;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String customeEmail;


    public long getCustomerd() {
        return customerd;
    }

    public void setCustomerd(long customerd) {
        this.customerd = customerd;
    }


    public String getCustomeEmail() {
        return customeEmail;
    }

    public void setCustomeEmail(String customeEmail) {
        this.customeEmail = customeEmail;
    }
}
```

This is my service method:

```
   public Order orderDetails (@RequestBody Order order){

       String username = "username";
       String password = "password";
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);

       // request url
       String url = "https://test.myshopify.com/admin/orders/2013413015655.json";

       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

       HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

        ResponseEntity<Order> response = restTemplate.exchange(
           url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Order.class);

       return order;
   }
```

This is my Controller Method:

```
    @GetMapping("/orderdetails")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    public Order getBasicAut(Order order){
        return basicAuth.orderDetails(order);
    }
```

Comment: You've annotated the service argument with RequestBody, but it's not a controller, so this annotation is useless. On the other hand, you have not annotated the controller method argument with RequestBody (and it's a GET, so it doesn't have a body anyway). And finally, your service sends a request to myshopify, but does nothing at all with the response. I'm not sure why yur methods have an argument in the first place. And I guess you should return the response from myshopify, instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with what my methods were returning. They both have to return a ResponseEntity of type Order as in:

```
public ResponseEntity<Order> orderDetails (@RequestBody Order order){

   String username = "username";
   String password = "password";
   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);

   // request url
   String url = "https://test.myshopify.com/admin/orders/2013413015655.json";

   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

   HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

   ResponseEntity<Order> response = restTemplate.exchange(
           url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Order.class);


   return response;
}
```

And my Controller to:

```
@GetMapping("/orderdetails")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
public ResponseEntity<Order> getBasicAut(Order order){
    return basicAuth.orderDetails(order);
}
```

Comment: It is important to take into account the comment from @jb-nizet The  `@RequestBody` annotation should not be used in the service because it ruins proper isolation of your service.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your REST to produce the JSON content

```
@GetMapping(path = "/orderdetails", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
```

Specifically, those codes below work well

```
@RestController
public class JsonController {

  @GetMapping(path = "/orderdetails", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
  public Order sendJsonBack() {
    final Order order = new Order();
    order.setCustomerd(123L);
    order.setCustomeEmail("mail@gmail.com");
    return order;
  }
}


@Data
class Order implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4258392267221190600L;

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private long customerd;

  @JsonProperty("email")
  private String customeEmail;

}
```